# Ashkenaz Tachanun

Tags: tachanun, nusach-ashkenaz

Why does Ashkenaz start at Rachum Vechanun, and not say the first part (like Nusach Sefard does). What's the basis for the disagreement?

Comment: What is "the first part"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viddui comes from the mekubalim and is recommended by the ARI. Minhag Ashkenaz did not adopt this addition to their siddur. Those influenced by the ARI did include it; among them are Sefardim and "Nusach Sefard" - meaning the Chassidic Ashkenazim. The basis for the disagreement is whether to accept Kabbalistic Kavanot into Davening or not.

Just an interesting side point, in Eretz Yisroel even Nussach Ashkenaz says the Viddui  because Talmidei HaGra took it from the Sefaradim in Eretz Yisroel. They also adopted saying of the Ketores at the end of the weekday Shacharis for the same reason.

[Source](http://ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v55/mj_v55i09.html#CAN)

Comment: Many Ahkenazim in Eretz Yisroel say Viddui and Ketores, but Nusach Ashkenaz does not change depending on where you are in the world (besides duchaning). I no quite a few Ashkenazi shuls in Eretz Yisroel who do not change their minhogim to be like the Talmidei HaGra, but instead keep to the mesorah. And as we all know מסורה סיג לתורה.